# Подмена класса в label

Tags: html, css

При заполнении формы, если `input` заполнен неправильно и выдает ошибку `:invalid`, то нужно добавлять класс .error в `label`, к которому относится этот `input` и отменять если `input` становится `:valid`.

```css
.error {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="" for="email">e-mail</label>
  <input name="email" type="email">
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input:invalid{
    color: #f00;
}
```

И код:

```
<form>
<label class="" id="label1" for="email">e-mail</label>
<input name="email" type="email">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

$('input[name="email"]').on('keyup', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':invalid')) {
        $('#label1').addClass('error');
    }
    else{
        $('#label1').removeClass('error');
    }
})
```

Comment: вариант интересный, но нужно подменять класс по состоянию input-а

Comment: в чем проблема изменить на класс? Вместо
        $('#label1').css('color', 'red');
        $('#label1').addClass('error');
    И
        $('#label1').css('color', 'black');
        $('#label1').removeClass('error');

Comment: изменил свое сообщение на классы.

Answer (score 2):

```css
input {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
input[type="email"]:invalid + label.email {
  color: #f00;
}
input[type="email"]:valid + label.email {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input name="email" type="email">
<label class="email" for="email">E-mail</label>
```